# Passing data to ViewController via function prepare for segue isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, null

I'm trying to pass data to a ViewController using the function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ContactTableViewController
    {
        vc.invitationType = type
        print(vc.invitationType)
    }
}
```

It gets called alright, and I can print the `vc.invitationType`, so that variable is getting set in the new vc.

The problem is when the segue happens. In the new view controller, the line `print(inv)` isn't being executed, because `invitationType` is nil:

```
class ContactTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var invitationType: InvitationType?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let inv = invitationType {
            print(inv)
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

EDIT:
I thought I was using the segue defined at the Storyboard, but as it turned out, I was wrongly using a function of mine that instantiates another ViewController:

```
    let newVC = originVC.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewcontroller) as! VC
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = newVC
```

So the problem was that I ended up setting the variable `invitationType` in one instance and segueing to a different instance of `ContactTableViewController`.

Comment: A stupid clarification from my side - Can you just print(invitationType) in videoDidLoad of new viewController. Just comment out the if let condition

Comment: @Nitish The problem was that I had two instances of the same ViewController. See edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, probably the `view` is already loaded at that point, so `viewDidLoad` was called before you set the value to `invitationType`:

```
class ContactTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var invitationType: InvitationType? {
        didSet {
            print(">>> already loaded \(invitationType)")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let inv = invitationType {
            print(inv)
        }
    }
}
```

From the comments those two `ContactTableViewController` are not the same - you are messing up the segue somehow by instantiating another view controller that gets presented.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, I tried it and it's printing `">>> already loaded \(inv)"` exactly when I execute this line (not before): `vc.invitationType = type`. I believe that's because I'm setting this variable at that line.
I even tried moving `if let inv = invitationType` to `override func viewWillAppear` but it didn't help either.

Comment: @Rod how to you run the segue?

Comment: I set the segue in the storyboard, by control dragging from a UIButton to the ViewController I want.

Comment: @Rod can you show what exactly does `print(">>> already loaded \(inv)")` print in the console? please, do not describe, copy paste the output from the console

Comment: @MilanNosáľ what are you trying to show with that?  Of course the print statement will execute when you set the property; it doesn't tell you anything about the state of the view without an additional unconditional print statement in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Paulw11 the only logical explanation that comes to my mind for this is that the type is `nil`.. in that case the `didSet` will be called, but those `if let` conditions won't.. so I want to be sure that there is a value..

Comment: Actually `print(">>> already loaded \(inv)")` causes a compilation error, because inv is only being set at viewDidLoad(), but `print(">>> already loaded \(invitationType)")` prints the following: `>>> already loaded Optional(IPS.InvitationType.sms)` that is an enum value I'm setting to invitationType.

Comment: @ MilanNosáľ the variable type is not nil, its content is "IPS.InvitationType.sms", the same enum I'm trying to set.

Comment: Exactly, but you need another `print("loaded")` or similar in `viewDidLoad` to confirm the order of execution, or even better, use breakpoints in the debugger. Honestly though, moving the code to `viewWillAppear` should fix the issue

Comment: @Paulw11 I put a print at `viewDidLoad` and this is the printed output:
`>>> already loaded Optional(IPS.InvitationType.sms)
Optional(IPS.InvitationType.sms)
>>>ContactTableViewController did Load`.
Which leads me to believe that the order of execution is:
*set the variable: `vc.invitationType = type`
*print it: `print(vc.invitationType)`
*print at the viewDidLoad: `print(">>>ContactTableViewController did Load")`

Comment: @Rod  try to confirm that those calls are made on the same instance.. in `viewDidLoad` try to `print(self)`, and in `prepareForSegue` try to `print(vc)` and compare the outputs to confirm we are looking at the same instance

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ  That's it! They are different instances:
`<IPS.ContactTableViewController: 0x7fe589720860>
<IPS.ContactTableViewController: 0x7fe58976b780>`
Any idea how to correct this, though?

Comment: @Rod you'll have to show more of your project, cause right now from what you showed I have no idea what might be causing that

Comment: @Rod I guess the whole code of the `ViewController` that has `prepareForSegue` would help - edit the answer and include it

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for helping to improve the quality of the answer

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ You were right, I was instantiating another view controller in the segue part. My bad. It's working now. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @Rod cool.. we should update the question/answer so that when something similar happens to someone else, (s)he can learn from this

Comment: Just did! Thanks!